# reactJs on IE9 throwing errors

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

I managed to create a login form using `reactJs` :
https://jsbin.com/qehifu/1

I get this error on `IE9` (works fine on Chrome):

> SCRIPT5007 : Unable to get the property value "remove": null object or undefined
>
> SCRIPT5007 : Unable to get the property value "add": null object or undefined

```
    isValid: function (input) {
    //check required field
    if (input.getAttribute('required') != null && input.value ==="") {
        input.classList.add('error'); //add class error
        input.nextSibling.textContent = this.props.messageEmail; // show error message
        return false;
    }
    else {
        input.classList.remove('error');
        input.nextSibling.textContent = "";

        //rest of the file...

    }
```

can you guys help ? thanks

Comment: React should more or less work with ie9. Can you console.log  input.classList and input to get more insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassList` API was only introduced to IE in V10.

You could think about using a polyfill, like the one here > https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Solved. thanks for the fast reply. (+1 for the source)